java: incompatible types: T cannot be converted to T
I was working on a school assignment on generics, when I ran into a really weird error. I'm getting 5 incompatible types errors at compile time, but all of them bar 1 are saying that a type is incompatible with the exact same type.
Here is the code:
public class Utility <T> {

    ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // Insert the code here.
    public Utility() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Utility(List<T> list) {
        this.list = new ArrayList<T>(list);
    }

    public <T extends Comparable<T>> int linearSearch(T item) {
        int position = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (item.compareTo(list.get(i)) == 0) {
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return position;
    }

    public <T> void mergeList(List<T> list) {
        for (T obj: this.list)
            list.add(obj);
    }

    public <T> boolean containList(List<T> list) {
        if (this.list.containsAll(list)) {
            this.list = new ArrayList<T>();
            for (T obj: list)
                this.list.add(obj);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public <T> void removeZero(List<T> myList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
            if (MyInteger.isZero(myList.get(i))) {
                myList.remove(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }

}

Here is a screenshot of the build output:
java: incompatible types: T cannot be converted to T

The <T>s in the method signatures and the <T> in the class signature are all their own separate individual type parameters that just happen to have the same name. And the former are shadowing/hiding the latter. You should probably remove the <T> from each method. Also, given your linearSearch method, the class-level T should probably be bounded by Comparable<T>.

Are you assuming that T is always the same type?  Or do you mean for it to be different types sometimes?  Can you elaborate?

Note this code from the tutorial: interface Collection<E> {     public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c);     public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends E> c); }  I believe this is the correct syntax for many of your methods.

Also this comment from the same tutorial: If a generic method appears inside a generic class, it's a good idea to avoid using the same names for the type parameters of the method and class, to avoid confusion. The same applies to nested generic classes.

Text should be as text, not images of text.  Use text copy-and-paste to ensure accuracy.

Your problem here is you've actually declared several type parameters, then called them all T.  Each <T> that you've written straight after the word public, at the start of a method, makes a new type parameter, whose scope is just that one method.  That means that T used within that method is NOT the same as the T declared at the top of the class.
This should be clear to see if I show you your code, but using T1, T2 and so on for each of the type parameters.
public class Utility <T1> {

    ArrayList<T1> list = new ArrayList<>();

    // Insert the code here.
    public Utility() {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Utility(List<T1> list) {
        this.list = new ArrayList<T1>(list);
    }

    public <T2 extends Comparable<T2>> int linearSearch(T2 item) {
        int position = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (item.compareTo(list.get(i)) == 0) {
                position = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return position;
    }

    public <T3> void mergeList(List<T3> list) {
        for (T3 obj: this.list)
            list.add(obj);
    }

    public <T4> boolean containList(List<T4> list) {
        if (this.list.containsAll(list)) {
            this.list = new ArrayList<T4>();
            for (T4 obj: list)
                this.list.add(obj);
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public <T5> void removeZero(List<T5> myList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
            if (MyInteger.isZero(myList.get(i))) {
                myList.remove(i);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
}

Now your problem is that your type parameters don't match up.  For example, in the for loop in mergeList, you're using a variable of type T3 to  iterate through an ArrayList<T1>, and there's no guarantee that T1 and T3 will have any relationship to each other at all.
To fix your code, you want to get rid of the <T> that occurs after public at the start of each method, so that the code inside the method refers to the  T declared at class level, instead of a new, overriding T.
The one place where that will cause you a problem is at the start of linearSearch, where you've introduced a restriction on T.  You most likely want to move that restriction to the class level declaration of T.  In other words, the class should start with
public class Utility<T extends Comparable<T>>

since you want every mention of T within the class to refer to a type that extends Comparable.

There are two T parameters: one on linearSearch and another on Utility.
Solution:

change class Utility <T> to class Utility <T extends Comparable<T>>
change <T extends Comparable<T>> int linearSearch(T item) to int linearSearch(T item)

